# Having trouble running this C++ code?

Tags: c++

I am having trouble running this grading problem and I'm not sure what's wrong with it. I am completely new to C++ and I know that it's terrible, but any help would be appreciated. I'm using DevC++ for my class and the error keeps returning to the getScore in the first brackets, and I don't know what's wrong with it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void getScore();
void calcAverage(int s1, int s2, int s3);
int findLowest(int s1, int s2, int s3);
string name;

int main()

{
getScore (int s1, int s2, int s3);


}
void getScore(int s1, int s2, int s3)
{
string name;

cout << "Please enter your name: ";
cin >> name;

cout << "Please enter the grade for test 1: ";
cin >> s1;
cout << "Please enter the grade for test 2: ";
cin >> s2;
cout << "Please enter the grade for test 3: ";
cin >> s3;

calcAverage(s1, s2, s3);

}
void calcAverage(int s1, int s2, int s3)
{

int average;
int lowest; 

lowest = findLowest(s1, s2, s3);

average = ((s1 + s2 + s3) - lowest)/2;

cout << "Congratulations " << name << "!" <<endl;
cout << " " <<endl;
cout << "The average of the two test scores with the lowest dropped is: ";
cout << average << endl;

}
int findLowest(int s1, int s2, int s3)
{

int lowest = s1;

if (lowest > s2)
    lowest = s2;

if (lowest > s3)
    lowest = s3;

return lowest;
```

}

Comment: You haven't told us what the error is...

Answer (score 1):

When calling a function, you have to pass variables, which you declare somewhere before the function call. So you call `getScore()` like this:

```
void main()
{
    int a = 5, b = 10, c = 15;
    getScore(a, b, c);
}
```

Also, when you declare a prototype for a function, it has to have the same parameters as in the body implementation.

Comment: The parameters should be passed by reference if the function is going to modify them.